# Passing argument string which contains spaces and quotes

Tags: c++, qt

Using [`QProcess::startDetached`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html#startDetached), I need to pass a dynamic argument list which is coming from another process to the starting process.

> **`const QString & prog, const QStringList & args, const QString & workingDirectory ...)`**
>
> Note that arguments that contain spaces are not passed to the process
>   as separate arguments.
>
> ...
>
> **Windows:** Arguments that contain spaces are wrapped in quotes. The
>   started process will run as a regular standalone process.

I have a string which contains below text, It comes from an external program without any control on it:

```
-c "resume" -c "print 'Hi!'" -c "print 'Hello World'"
```

I need to pass above string to `QProcess::startDetached` so that the starting program catches it as same as above string.

Do I have to parse the string and build a string-list? Or anyone has a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use a QStringList at all for the arguments, as there is this overloaded function: -

```
bool QProcess::startDetached(const QString & program)
```

Which, as the documentation states: -

> Starts the program program in a new process. program is **a single string of text containing both the program name and its arguments**. The arguments are separated by one or more spaces.
>
> The program string can also contain quotes, to ensure that arguments containing spaces are correctly supplied to the new process.

You may need to replace " with \", but you can do that from a QString

You can use `parseCombinedArgString` (from Qt's source code) to parse:

```
QStringList parseCombinedArgString(const QString &program)
{
    QStringList args;
    QString tmp;
    int quoteCount = 0;
    bool inQuote = false;
    // handle quoting. tokens can be surrounded by double quotes
    // "hello world". three consecutive double quotes represent
    // the quote character itself.
    for (int i = 0; i < program.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (program.at(i) == QLatin1Char('"'))
        {
            ++quoteCount;
            if (quoteCount == 3)
            {
                // third consecutive quote
                quoteCount = 0;
                tmp += program.at(i);
            }
            continue;
        }
        if (quoteCount)
        {
            if (quoteCount == 1)
                inQuote = !inQuote;
            quoteCount = 0;
        }
        if (!inQuote && program.at(i).isSpace())
        {
            if (!tmp.isEmpty())
            {
                args += tmp;
                tmp.clear();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            tmp += program.at(i);
        }
    }
    if (!tmp.isEmpty())
        args += tmp;
    return args;
}
```

Comment: How about the overload which has `workingDirectory` parameter? Can I have the overload that you mentioned and set the working directory?

Comment: There is a separate function call QProcess::setWorkingDirectory: "Sets the working directory to dir. QProcess will start the process in this directory." So call that before you call call startDetached. However, you may need to create an instance of QProcess for this to work.

Comment: `startDetached` is a static method, are you sure that it uses the internal attributes of `QProcess` for `startDetached`?

Comment: A good point. According to this thread, it was a defined as a bug in 2010, but may have been fixed. If not, it suggests to overload the function to support it yourself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265946/set-environment-variables-for-startdetached-qprocess

Comment: Looking at the source code, at line 2151, the environment variable is still ignored: https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/ec76b17145c6449a5d90a1052635f30971e7fa4d:src/corelib/io/qprocess.cpp#L5

Comment: However, you could copy the function parseCombinedArgString from line 1906 to create the arg list for you and just call the startDetached with the arg list and environment.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have to "parse" the string, splitting it at the correct positions, and enter each sub-string into the `QStringList` object you pass to the function.

Comment: Isn't it weird? Passing an argument string usually is a very easy task. Why `startDetached` needs `QStringList` as all? How about more complicated arguments?

Comment: @MM. Probably because the function can't reasonably parse the argument string if it creates an `argv`-style array.

Comment: +1 I've used `parseCombinedArgString` from Qt's source code which parses the string. You're right that I have to parse it.